# Constant updating and calling submitchanges: This entity is currently read-only ria services

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am making a Todo Type of application where a user can make a note and constantly move the note around the screen. On every change of position of "note" I need to save it into database:

The typical code for this is:

```
 private void SaveChanges()
    {
        if (!_context.IsSubmitting)
        {
            this.busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
            _context.SubmitChanges(subOp =>
            {

                this.busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
                if (subOp.Error != null)
                {
                    ErrorWindow window = new ErrorWindow(subOp.Error.Message);
                    window.Show();
                }

            }, null);
        }
    }
```

However as you can see I am blocking the UI by using busyindicator and stopping the user to do any activity while it is submitting. This is bad especially for this application. So as an alternative I tried to move this code onto a different thread using this code:

```
    private void SaveChanges()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitcall =>
        {
            if (!_context.IsSubmitting)
            {
                //this.busyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
                _context.SubmitChanges(subOp =>
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        //this.busyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
                        if (subOp.Error != null)
                        {
                            ErrorWindow window = new ErrorWindow(subOp.Error.Message);
                            window.Show();
                        }
                    });

                }, null);
            }

        });
    }
```

This works and the application still remains responsive. However now while the context is submitting the changes and the user works with the same note by moving it around the screen etc the binding try to change the entity's properties and I get exception:

**This entity is currently read-only**

I understand this is obvious because the context is submitting the changes. However is there any way by which I can keep the application responsive by not showing the dumb busy indicator and still not get these exceptions?

Comment: why are you savin on every change ? why not wait till the user stops changing before you submit ?

Comment: Saving on every change meant "User stops moving the note". I need to save when the user has stopped moving the note. Typically this is what happens: 1) User "stops" moving the note 2) submitchanges fires 3) during submitchanges, user again moves the note and exception fires.

Comment: that sounds like your code doesn't deal correctly with reentrancy... why don't you just submit the second change AFTER the first submit is finished ?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. "why don't you just submit the second change AFTER the first submit is finished ?" How will I know when the 2nd change is going to happen? The user may move the note around the note not just 2 times but N times. How can I know that the user has finished moving the note Nth time and so save the changes :)?

Comment: That's not what I meant: I don't mean wait till the user made all changes and doesn't make anymore change BUT just postpone the second/third etc. `submitchanges` till the previous `submitchanges` has finished executing

Comment: Yahia, problem is not of submitchanges happening concurrently. Problem is when you are submitting the changes and simultaneously modifying the properties of the entity. Submitchanges will never happen concurrently because I have already written if context is not submitting the changes then only submit it in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During SubmitChanges, all changed properties are set to read only. In your case, it is the position properties. I am guessing that the properties are bound to the note position.

Possiblities:

1. Do not bind to the entity in your DomainContext. Bind to a client local object with property changed events (perhaps a clone of the entity). Use the property changed events to try to copy the change to the context entity. If it fails (read-only), you may want to add code to retry later.
2. Use EntityGraph partial submit from RIA Services Contrib. 
   riaservicescontrib.codeplex.com
   Check the discussions / blogs - code is provided to clone the EntityGraph into a temp context and submit the temp context. I do not think you will want to Synchronize on completion because that would probably overwrite the new position and cause the window to jump around. Just submit and forget. 
   If you are adding the entity on the client and it needs auto generated key properties returned from the server (identity, etc.). Then, do not use a temp context / partial submit for the add. Block the UI and submit the add normally so your client properties are updated on completion and a partial submit is not called before your key values have been set.

I would be interested in any other possible solutions.

Comment: I like your solutions. One other solution is using Stored procedure instead of calling SubmitChanges.

Answer (score 0):

You could also maintain a threadsafe count of the number of outstanding submit operations and pop the next one off in the callback of the current submit operation:

```
public static int myPendingSubmitOperationsCount;
...
myDataContext.SubmitChanges(mySubmitCallback, null);
...
mySubmitCallback(SubmitOperation so)
{
     //Do important stuff
     if(myPendingSubmitOperationsCount > 0)
     {
         myDataContext.SubmitChanges(mySubmitCallback, null);
         myPendingSubmitOperationsCount -= 1;
     }
}
```